# tomcat 6 - how to run 2 apps as default?

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have 2 tomcat apps I want to run on the same server, is it possible to have tomcat be smart enough to say if comes in on domain 1 go to app 1 as default and domain 2, go to app 2 as default?

Right now one of the apps is renamed to be called ROOT so it gets all the default traffic regardless of domain.

If not I guess I need to add another ip to the box and run 22 instances of the server? If I have to go this route, how to I force it to listen on a specific ip instead of the default interface?

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tomcat [virtual hosts](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

you better use modjk http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html or
you can use mod_proxy http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html to do this.